# How do I display contents of a file where PATH environment changes are made?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Say I change the `$PATH` environment variable. If I'm asked to display the contents of the file where this change happened, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. There isn't any way to find out where environment variable changes came from, after the fact.

You could insert some `echo` commands which would display the name of the file as changes are being made, but the changes are not tracked, with respect to which file made a particular change.